# Copy cell that equals cell value from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 worksheets: Worksheet A, B, and C.

Worksheet B has cells that are pulling information from Worksheet A and placing in specific visual format.

I then alter the color of the cells on Worksheet B (the same cells whose value is equal to Worksheet A) and trying to copy both values and colors to Worksheet 3 in one column.

```
Sub copycellcolor1()
Dim rField As Range
Dim idCell As Range
Dim r1WS As Worksheet
Dim rrWS As Worksheet

Set r1WS = Worksheets("RACK 1")
Set rField = r1WS.Range("C6:N13")
Set rrWS = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull")

For Each idCell In rField

    If idCell.Interior.color = RGB(204, 204, 255) Then
        idCell.Copy rrWS.Range("A1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
Next idCell

rrWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

I'm getting the correct color on Worksheet 3, but the value is `#REF!` because the actual value of the cell is referring to Worksheet A.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are copying a formula. If you want the formula copied you may have to review the referencing (look at the $ signs in it). If you want to copy the value (result of the formula) use `Copy` and `PasteSpecial xlValues`.

Comment: I appreciate the response!  I can bring the values or the color over.  Just not both.  I've tried about every VBA paste special option available.  

Perhaps writing a macro to input the data from Worksheet A into the specific organization I need on Worksheet B might work?

Comment: `End(xlUp)` works like this:- "From the defined cell, go xlUp, until the End of the column and return the cell found there as a range." In your code `.Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0)` is the "defined cell". Given that rrWS.Rows.Count = 1048576, rrWS.Rows.Count - 1 must equal 1048575. Usually that shouldn't make a difference but if you want to define a cell you need to supply the column as well as the row. Therefore what you mean is `rrWS.Cells(rrWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)`

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha!  I appreciate the explanation!  I'm 1 week into VBA, still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PasteSpecial

You're using the wrong way to [copy/paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy). Try the following:

```
    If idCell.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255) Then
        With rrWS.Range("A1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            idCell.Copy
            ' Paste values.
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ' Paste formats.
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    End If
    
    ' This is a little bit ridiculous, but it works.
    If idCell.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255) Then
        With rrWS.Range("A1").Offset(rrWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Paste values.
            .Value = idCell.Value
            ' Paste formats.
            idCell.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    End If
```